# Can a flying construct escape from an open bag of holding on its own?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

My group had a debate on a particular event in play last night: a flying construct was grappled and put into someone's bag of holding. Some time later, another player opened the bag for three rounds to stuff items in. The construct used that opportunity to escape the bag.

Was this reasonable and possible? Does opening the bag create a gateway that can be seen and used by a being inside the bag? One of the players believed that the construct couldn't leave the bag unless pulled out, like a haversack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, it's possible

> The bag of holding opens into a nondimensional space: Its inside is larger than its outside dimensions.

All that truly occurs with a bag of holding or similar items is that they are in a pocket dimension of finite space.  As long as the creature has a fly speed to reach the opening, which depending on the bag type can be as far as (roughly) 250' without getting into the algebra.  Now, if the players are waiting for the construct to try an escape, they can have a held action to perform an attack of opportunity, most notably a grapple to stop it from escaping, but if they aren't expecting it they are flatfooted and thus have no recourse when the critter breaks free unless the DM in question gives them a Reflex save for some reason.

However, you can also argue that if the lighting and sounds on either side of the bag are the same, then the construct may need a Perception check to notice that the bag has even been opened.

But! The main concern I would have is the following:

> If the bag is overloaded, or if sharp objects pierce it (from inside or outside), the bag ruptures and is ruined. All contents are lost forever.

Comment: Are you suggesting the construct would deliberately rupture the bag and thus be lost forever, out of spite?

Comment: Depending on the nature of the construct it may have sharp edges and without an Int score things might get crazy.

Comment: @Scott [sometimes that's exactly what you want to do](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31824/permanently-hiding-items-objects)