# Can you cast spells through planar gates?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, portals

Is it possible to cast spells through planar portals, like those created by the [gate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/gate) spell or a [portable hole](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/portable-hole)?

There are some cases such as *Rope Trick*, that have explict language to block this. Gate and Portable Hole have no such language.

There is this answer, but it is for [D&D 3.5](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/109797/can-magic-pass-through-planar-portals). In [this Q&A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/198226/what-is-the-distance-to-points-in-another-dimension-if-there-is-a-portal-or-gat) multiple answers argue that casting into a portable hole is not the same as casting through a gate in general. [This one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/198226/what-is-the-distance-to-points-in-another-dimension-if-there-is-a-portal-or-gat/198231#198231), argues gates are much more varied in nature than a simple portable hole opening, and [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/198226/what-is-the-distance-to-points-in-another-dimension-if-there-is-a-portal-or-gat/198235#198235) even argues that extradimensional spaces are different from planes to begin with.

This may mean the answer is only "we can't say in general, ask your DM", but clearly the answer is not simply "look how it works for a portable hole", as in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/125752/are-you-considered-out-of-range-of-spells-and-weapons-when-inside-the-hole-of-a).

Comment: I had not found the other question (was looking for gate spell when searching). I agree it is a duplicate. Should I delete the question or is it a useful question to leave around?

Comment: Duplicates are generally fine to keeep around.

Comment: I don't think that the arguments make this question any less of a duplicate, unfortunately, the answers may make it less conclusive than desired.

Comment: @Akixkisu, while I do not understand this conclusion, I can add a bit more direct evidence when I find the time. Let it be as is for now